# Using inheritance for adding fields in my domain layer

Tags: java

I have created a class named `Base` that have one field that stores a `UUID` since I want all objects in my system to have that. I also want to have a field named `id` on all objects that can be stored in the database. I won't add it to `Base` since not all objects in my domain layer will be persisted to a database. I could create another class which inherits from `Base` and adds this field and then let all classes that needs both inherit from that.

Should it be avoided to create hieracies which exists for the purpose of adding fields like this? Are there better options?

Comment: You might choose to use an interface instead, and require a `getUUID()` method (and a `getDatabaseId()` method for DB-serializable objects)

Comment: But if the equals and hashCode is based on the uuid, then I would need the class, and I also want a `isNew()` method for all objects that have the `id` field to check if it has been persisted to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For very simple applications you can use inheritance only. But as the application grows complex your classes will be more flexible if you use composition. So, define common behavior, common fields in interfaces and require the classes with these common behaviors to implement them. Provide implementations for the common interfaces and let your classes delegate calls to the implementing classes.

Here is an example:

```
interface Uniqueness {
    long getUUID();
    void setUUID(long uuid);
}

interface Storable {
    long getId();
    void setId(long id);
}

class UniquenessSupport implements Uniqueness {

    private long uuid;

    @Override
    public long getUUID() {
        return uuid;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUUID(long uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
}

class StorableSupport implements Storable {
    private long id;

    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class Some implements Uniqueness, Storable {

    private UniquenessSupport uniquenessSupport;
    private StorableSupport storableSupport;

    public Some() {
        uniquenessSupport = new UniquenessSupport();
        storableSupport = new StorableSupport();
    }

    @Override
    public long getUUID() {
        return uniquenessSupport.getUUID();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUUID(long uuid) {
        uniquenessSupport.setUUID(uuid);
    }

    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return storableSupport.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(long id) {
        storableSupport.setId(id);
    }
}
```

In this simple case there is a lot of boilerplate code, but as you add more fields and methods to your classes this is the only way to have flexibility and avoid code duplication. If you will have some more interfaces, let's say: `Payable`, `Sendable`, `Returnable` and want to create a new class that is only `Payable` and has `Uniqueness`, you employ the suitable interface and support classes: `Uniqueness` + `UniquenessSupport` and `Payable` + `PayableSupport` only.

On the other side, if using inheritance you would extend some Base class that would need to contain all methods from `Payable`, `Sendable`, etc. in order to accommodate all needs, but your class would need to be only `Payable` and has `Uniqueness`. By inheritance you will make it also `Returnable`, `Storable`, etc.

Comment: I agree with your suugestion

Comment: Favor composition over inheritance :)

Comment: Hmm...So if you create one interface named Uniqueness (in the lack of a better name) which require a getter and setter for the UUID, and another interface named Storable which require a getter and setter for the Id then you have to create two implementation classes, and then you need eiter have a field I guess in each domain class that wants this functionality and create another set of setter/getter or you still need to inherit these through a hierachy? Please show an example because I am not sure if I understand this.

Comment: Thanks for providing the example, awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

That's really what inheritance is for, to localize class properties / behaviors that are common between many different classes.  Your example is fairly simplistic, but still seems like a reasonable use of inheritance.

Comment: This may not supply enough flexibility. lets say that in the future more entities wull be persisted to file. They will extenend some DbEntity class. but now a class cant be petsisted both to db and file.

Comment: @omerschleifer - possibly.  I can't possibly cover all the different possible roadmaps for such a feature :)  Just mentioning that this is what inheritance is for.. localizing common properties / behaviors into single parent classes.

Answer (score 0):

If all that id does is supply simple get/set I would use an interface: IDbEntity with methods like getId() and possibly setId().

Comment: But then every implementing class will still have to hold an id member. And this is for every class in that domain

Comment: Yes that is true in Java where there are no properties like .net and no mulipule inheritence like c++. this is a compormise, but like I wrote in my comment it will supply better flexibilty. In more complex cases a composition may be cosidered instead of inheritance